# executing django query in same statement

Tags: python, database, django, connection

This might be a silly question. Is there a way to execute multiple queries in one `execute` statement?

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("Select * from my_tables; show tables;")
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: No you can't do that, `cursor.execute(sql, [params])` It takes one sql statement and params list (optional). Maybe you are looking for subqueries ([MySQL Subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html))?

Comment: you can always execute `raw` SQL statements like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies. The reason that i want to do this is because i am creating a sql injectable platform for class room purposes. So wiht cursore.execute(sql, [params]) will not work in that aspect. Do you know of any way that i can perform sql inject queries in python?

Comment: @user1817081 What DB API are you using?

Comment: @Aya i am using MySQLDB

Comment: @user1817081 ...and what version of MySQL?

Comment: @Aya the version is 5.1.69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS` and `CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS` options are enabled by default in `MySQLdb` (which is quite disturbing), so you can do something like this...

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> conn = MySQLdb.connect(db='test')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute('select * from foo; show tables;')
2L
>>> cur.fetchall()
((1L,), (1L,))
>>> cur.nextset()
1
>>> cur.fetchall()
(('foo',),)
```

If you want to demonstrate an example which makes changes to an InnoDB table, you'll have to commit the transaction with something like...

```
>>> cur.execute('select * from foo; insert into foo values (123);')
2L
>>> cur.nextset()
1
>>> conn.commit()
>>> cur.execute('select * from foo')
3L
>>> cur.fetchall()
((1L,), (1L,), (123L,))
```

Check out [PEP249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) for the meaning of all the return values.